# Is bootstrap modal not allowing me to type in a redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a form in a bootstrap modal but when I implemented it as a redux-form, it won't allow me to type in anything in the fields (despite the characters typed are being payloaded and are changing the state). What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

class ItemsContainer extends Component{
render(){
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    //markup stuff...
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="modal-body form-group">
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="nombre">Nombre</label>
              <br/>
              <Field name="nombre" component="input" type="text" placeholder='¿Qué vendes?' className = 'form-control'/>
            </div>

    //more form markup

 ItemsContainer = reduxForm({
   form: 'articulo' // a unique name for this form
 })(ItemsContainer);

 export default ItemsContainer;
```

Comment: Is it working fine without `modal` ?

Comment: Are you using Immutable.js by any chance?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja it doesn't.

Comment: @MarkChandler I'm not

Comment: Actually, when I ran the 'simple' example from the redux-form repo, running 'npm install' didn't install the dependencies successfully